# How to shuffle file before each session?

Tags: php, shuffle

I searched all day on this forum but couldn't find any answer.

I use following php code to display the next line from `myfile.txt` on each pageload (looping when gone through entire file):

```
<?php
session_start();
$item = file("myfile.txt");
$itemCount = count($item);

if ($_SESSION['sess_row'] === NULL) {
$_SESSION['sess_row'] = 0;
} else {
$_SESSION['sess_row'] = ($_SESSION['sess_row'] + 1) % $itemCount;
}

echo $item[$_SESSION['sess_row']];
?>
```

Now I want to shuffle the lines in `myfile.txt` before each session.

For example, if `myfile.txt` contains 5 lines, it now displays lines in same order every session: `123451234512345...`

With shuffle it should display one session: `325413254132541...`, another session: `413254132541325...`, another session: `142351423514235...`, and so on.

How can above code be changed to shuffle `myfile.txt` before each session?

Comment: Every session or every refresh of the page?

Comment: You shoud not shuffle a file, but the output. Have you thought about concurent users?

Comment: a db would be a billion times more efficent

Answer (score 0):

Use [shuffle](http://php.net/manual/en/function.shuffle.php) to shuffle your array each time.

```
$item = file("myfile.txt");
shuffle($item);
```

If you need to have different number for each user, you should have a database or something (it could be just a single file containing one number) to keep track of how many of your items are already assigned to users. Each time, read that number (call it cursor), assign the number associated with that cursor, increment the cursor by one and write it back to the file (or database ...)

Comment: Sorry, I tried that but it doesn't work, with shuffle($item); it displays simply random: 353321411213551...
My aim is to not display the same line twice before all lines have been gone through.

Comment: That's another issue which you can not solve just by randomizing.

Comment: I added more info about that to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you need unique data, you can use [array_unique](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-unique.php):

```
$item = file("myfile.txt");
$item = array_unique($items);
shuffle($item);
```